# why does C++ give me an error when inserting unique pointer into unordered map?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

in a class with the following member and method:

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<test::Test>> m_Tests;
    
    void test::TestMenu::addTest(const std::string &testName, std::unique_ptr<test::Test> test) {
        m_Tests.emplace(testName, test);
    }
```

called like this:

```
testMenu.addTest("Test Clear Color", std::make_unique<test::TestClearColor>());
```

The compiler delivers the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'
          std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

My question is why is C++ giving me this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
m_Tests.emplace(testName, test);
```

will try to copy `test`, because (a) it is an *lvalue* expression, (b) expressions never have reference type, and (c) `emplace` does not take an lvalue reference.

`unique_ptr`s cannot be copied.

This is what `std::move` is for!

```
m_Tests.emplace(testName, std::move(test));
```

Now you have an rvalue expression, which is perfectly suited to bind to the rvalue reference that `emplace` *does* take.

I'm actually slightly slightly lying here, and things are a bit more complicated since `emplace` is variadic. But whatever. The important thing is that you're creating another link in the chain of ownership for this `unique_ptr`, ultimately passing ownership on to the map, and `std::move` is the way to do that.